# why is the shape of embed_input 1000?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have gone through this code to colorize greyscale images but unable to understand the fusion part and why is the shape of embed_input 1000.
https://github.com/satyam671/Colorizing-greysclae-images-using-deep-learning/blob/master/Full.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The code is based on the above architecture. It uses an encoder (the above part) with mostly convolutional layers, but it also uses an InceptionResNetv2 as a feature extractor. It uses the 1000 flattened features as a feature vector from the InceptionResNetv2 and does a fusion with the encoder and then uses the decoder.

If you go to line 93 (generate training data) you'll find a function.

```
def image_a_b_gen(batch_size):
    for batch in datagen.flow(Xtrain, batch_size=batch_size):
        grayscaled_rgb = gray2rgb(rgb2gray(batch))
        embed = create_inception_embedding(grayscaled_rgb) # this is where the 1000 length feature vector is extracted
        lab_batch = rgb2lab(batch)
        X_batch = lab_batch[:,:,:,0]
        X_batch = X_batch.reshape(X_batch.shape+(1,))
        Y_batch = lab_batch[:,:,:,1:] / 128
        yield ([X_batch, create_inception_embedding(grayscaled_rgb)], Y_batch)
```

`create_inception_embedding` function does the feature extraction finally fusion is done.

```
# Fusion
fusion_output = RepeatVector(32 * 32)(embed_input) 
fusion_output = Reshape(([32, 32, 1000]))(fusion_output)
```

Here, the feature vector is repeated across the encoder output as shown in the diagram.

Comment: Thankyou. When I am running Inception.predict, why can't I predict without using the graph?. It throws an error as : Tensor Tensor("predictions_2/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.